# How to import the object with its texture?

Tags: texturing

I have an object file and texture files but I don't know how to apply the texture to the object file.

I downloaded this file:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/eyes-d031b85bead04c6fa03301ea81ec15ce

It's free. I encourage you to download it. It has other the obj file and all the texture .png files.

And it has the object file and the texture files:

[image]

[image]

I go to material properties and change the base color to this image, but it doesn't show the eye like it's supposed to, and there's no way to pick what eye color to apply.

How to pick the specific eye color?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the eye_opacity.png mask, so the iris is visible through the sclera.

1. Switch to *Material Preview* shading
2. Add the `Eye_opacity.png` texture to the Alpha socket
3. (and change *Blend mode* to *Alpha Hashed* if you're in Eevee)

[image]